# File names in OS X appearing with question marks

Tags: macos

I have a number of files on my Mac whose names suddenly started containing question marks.

When I examine them in Windows, they look fine. Same if I fire up the Ruby interactive shell (`irb`) and examine them in UTF8 mode.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the question marks?

**Update 1**: here's a screen capture of Finder with some file names with question marks.
[image]

**Update 2**: An example of a bad file name is: `Mac? ?users`.Output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Examining the above file name in ruby interactive shell with `filename.bytes{|c| puts c}` yields:

```
77
97
99
226
128
173
32
226
128
172
117
115
101
114
115
```

Comment: Can you provide examples (e.g. screenshots, or copy/paste the name)? Is it only in Finder, or also in Terminal?

Comment: Are the characters that are replaced by question marks special characters like accented characters, umlauts, characters in another language?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff no, they appear to be spaces or non-breaking spaces, I'm not sure.

Comment: How does it look like in Terminal when you run `ls`, and what is the result of editing a file name, copying it, and pasting it into a text document? Then save, and view in a hex editor. What is the byte sequence where that character is?

Comment: Running 'ls' shows the file names still with question marks. So does copy pasting the file name. The byte sequence at the question mark is always 3F, which makes sense since that's a question mark in ASCII. Could this be a result of Finder failing to correctly interpret UTF8?

Comment: If those are the bytes of the name "Mac...users" then you've got a bunch of non-ASCII characters there.  Everything 128 and larger is non-ASCII.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm assuming that usually Finder will interpret files names as UTF8 but somehow following the update it went to ASCII or similar. The question is is that true and if so how to go back to the previous situation?

Comment: It may be that those particular characters are not known the box.  I didn't attempt to look up the characters to see what they are.

Comment: They were showing OK before the latest OS update, so I think the locale or something similar may have been changed during the update. But I'm not sure which parameter to look into.