# OS X update results in question marks in file names

Tags: macos, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File names in OS X appearing with question marks](https://superuser.com/questions/389473/file-names-in-os-x-appearing-with-question-marks)

I've recently updated my Mac and now some file names contain question marks when viewed in Finder or the terminal. I suspect this is an encoding issue. An example of a bad file name is: `Mac? ?users`.Output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Examining the above file name in ruby interactive shell with `filename.bytes{|c| puts c}` yields:

```
77
97
99
226
128
173
32
226
128
172
117
115
101
114
115
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of the question marks?

Comment: You've already asked this, why ask it again?

Comment: Johnny, if there are changes or updates to your original question, please add them there. Posting the same question multiple times is not how to direct attention to it.